# Handling exceptions throughout the Activity/Fragment lifecycle

Tags: android, exception

So, I am trying to get a grip on the best way to hand exceptions in Android.

My current approach:

- Business logic/libraries typically throw exceptions up the call stack so that can be handled, unless the exception is partially expected and can be handled locally.
- All activity lifecycle functions such as onPause, onResume etc have try catch. They catch both Exception and my custom BusinessException class. For business exceptions I show a specific error and Exceptions show a generic Oops error, while logging the actual error in the background.
- Callbacks/listeners etc also have try/catch and upon exception call the onFail/error callback.

My issue is that I am ending up with a lot of try catch blocks. While that in itself isn't so bad, in each catch block I have boilerplate code for logging the error. i.e prepping key value pairs etc. It just seems very repetitive.

What do others do, or any opensource projects you are aware of that I should look at?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is largely my opinion.

> Business logic/libraries typically throw exceptions up the call stack so that can be handled, unless the exception is partially expected and can be handled locally.

The local-handling is fine. Throwing an exception to force local handling higher in the call stack is fine. Otherwise, I'd use an event bus to tell my UI layer (if it is around) that the problem occurred, possibly with a fallback mechanism to raise a `Notification` if the user needs to know about the problem and we are not in the foreground from a UI standpoint.

> All activity lifecycle functions such as onPause, onResume etc have try catch. They catch both Exception and my custom BusinessException class. For business exceptions I show a specific error and Exceptions show a generic Oops error, while logging the actual error in the background.
>
> Callbacks/listeners etc also have try/catch and upon exception call the onFail/error callback.

I would only worry about checked exceptions and expected unchecked exceptions (e.g., `ActivityNotFoundException` when invoking a third-party activity), following the same approach as I described earlier.

For everything else, I'd let me default uncaught exception handler deal with it, which in my case is usually [ACRA](http://www.acra.ch/).